# How to implement RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) in AWS Cognito with Serverless Lambda functions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, serverless

How to implement RBAC (Role-Based Access Control) in AWS Cognito with Serverless Lambda functions?

Most of the tutorial explains, attach IAM roles/policies and API Gateway,

```
Eg: http://12.in/list/employees
```

The above authorization works well, the system is only for one subscriber/organization.

How to implement the authorization in multiple subscriber/organization environments?

```
http://12.in/list/{org_id}/employees
```

Is it possible with Cognito?

Answer (score 1):

You can safely authorize with any of the claims you include in the token. That offers two places to easily add your user-to-org mapping.

1. As a custom user attribute (make sure it is immutable).
2. As a custom claim in a pre-token-generation trigger.